# How to get ratio of each odd indexed value with even indexed value of a data frame column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am fairly new to R programming. I am dealing with a data frame column with values -

```
> data$col
[1] 37.80 37.76 37.27 36.67
```

I would like to add a new column `col_ratio` in the data frame `data` such that the output of `data$col_ratio` is -

```
1.00 NA 1.01 NA
```

which is basically the ratio of `(37.80/37.76)` and `(37.27/36.67)`.

I tried doing -

```
> data$col_ratio <- data$col[1]/data$col[2]
> data$col_ratio[2] <- NA
```

But i am getting the output as -

```
> data$col_ratio
[1] 1.001059       NA 1.001059 1.001059
```

What am i missing to get the output as -

```
1.00 NA 1.01 NA
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq` is your friend here:

```
# idx gets 1, 3, 5, ...
idx = seq(1L, nrow(data), by=2L)

# initialize the column to be missing and real-valued
data$col_ratio = NA_real_
data$col_ratio[idx] = data$col[idx] / data$col[-idx]
```

`-idx` excludes the odd indices, i.e., it's the even indices.

Extra care will have to be taken in the case that `nrow(data)` is odd, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me an output like ```[1] 1.001059 1.016362 1.001059 1.016362``` where the expected output is ```[1] 1.001059 NA 1.001059 NA```.

Comment: sorry I have a typo, it's fixed now